# Replacing cube with rollup in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

A homework assignment I have asks the following question:

Show how to express \group by cube (a, b, c, d)" using rollup rather than cube.

I really don't have the faintest clue how to do this. Where would I start or where could I look for some help?

Answer (score 4):

Since this is an assignment I will point you to a [very good article about GROUP BY, ROLLUP and CUBE](http://www.rwijk.nl/AboutOracle/All%20About%20Grouping.ppt) by [Rob van Wijk](http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2009/10/all-about-grouping-at-oracle-openworld.html).

The two equivalence relations relevant here would be:

```
 GROUP BY CUBE ( set1, …, setn )
 ≡ GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (all possible combinations between () and (set1, …, setn) )
```

and the analogy with the cartesian product:

```
GROUP BY a, ROLLUP(b)
≡ GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (a), GROUPING SETS ((b), ())
≡ GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a,b), (a))
```

Comment: Ok, so after reading that... here's my proposed solution. Not sure if it's correct.

group by rollup(a, b, c, d, ab, ac, ad, bd, cd)

Would this work?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JasonMArcher Well, this is an assignment after all, I don't want to give away the solution =). I've included the relevant parts as hints though.